# iPhone Application runs on device connected, but unable to generate an IPA

Tags: ios, uikit, quartz-core, ios-frameworks

[image]

I have an Application that uses private Frameworks of Apple.
I have set the Build settings as screenshot. and placed all private frameworks' headers etc at that path.
When I try to run, It runs perfectly on a device.
But when I try to generate an IPA (archive the app) It gives errors like : 
Lexical or preprocessor issue 'IOSurface/IOSurfaceAPI.h' file not found.
Parse issue - Could not build module 'Quartzcore'
Parse issue - Could not build module 'UIKit'  Please Help.

Edit : Also Added the screenshot for the errors generated.

[image: Build Settings]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it resolved. In Build settings of the project--> Always search User paths Debug and Release modes, Both needed to be set to YES.